# Laravel query a model in a nested query?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have an Appointment model that has a relation to Employee and an Employee to a User. I am trying to query a list of appointments between specific dates ($weekStart and $weekEnd) and retrieve the appointments as well as the related Employees and Users.

So far this works, it returns all my Clients with all appointments and the assigned Employees/Users (Employees belong to User).

```
'clients' => Client::with('careType','appointments.employees.user')->get(),
```

However I wish to specify between dates on the appointments model. So I have this:

```
$data = [
  'clients' => Client::with(['appointments' => function ($query)  use ($weekStart, $weekEnd) {
        $query->whereBetween('starts_at', [$weekStart, $weekEnd]);
        }])->get(), 
];
```

In the above what is the syntax to also retrieve the employees and user models when I have a sub query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add your other models in your `Client`'s `with()` array.

```
$data = [
  'clients' => Client::with(['appointments' => function ($query)  use ($weekStart, $weekEnd) {
        $query->whereBetween('starts_at', [$weekStart, $weekEnd]);
        }, 'appointments.employees.user'])->get(), 
];
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. Not sure how. Does everything in the [] get evaluated as one? At first glance, I thought this would just reset the appointments and get() all rather than the query list.

Comment: Laravel's Eager Loading is a little complicated, but basically all string elements in the with statement (like `appointments.employees.user`) are evaluated first, and then any functions in the array will be evaluated and replace existing string elements.